# C# WebDriver problems with SwitchTo() with IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

When IE opens a second browser window using onclick.window.open() I need to do some processing on the second window and then close the window.

I have tried the following recomendations found on stackoverflow regarding window handles:

```
 string popupHandle = string.Empty;
    ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = selObj.Driver.WindowHandles;
    foreach (string handle in windowHandles)
    {
        if (handle != originalHandle)
        {
            popupHandle = handle;
            break;
        }
    }

    selObj.Driver.SwitchTo().Window((popupHandle));

    selObj.Driver.Close();

    selObj.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(originalHandle);
```

Before I execute this code I attempt to click on a control of the new window to change focus.

Webdriver cannot locate the control (I also tried to use the WebDriverWait class to wait for the second browse to fully load.

WebDriverWait also throws an exception after the wait seconds.

Upon attempting to execute the:

```
selObj.Driver.SwitchTo().Window((popupHandle));
```

I receive the following exception:

```
No response from server for url http://
```

I know this is C# and IE,  wondering if anyone has found a work around for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My trio C#+WebDriver+Ie works fine.

Yes - IE has to be focused.
Please, Try my code. Code works with IE, Chrome and Firefox

```
protected void SwitchToWindow(string name)
    {
        foreach (string item in _driver.WindowHandles)
        {
            if (_driver.SwitchTo().Window(item).Title.Contains(name))
            {
                _driver.SwitchTo().Window(item);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where _driver is selObj.Driver for your case.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but can be effective :

```
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions
                {
                    IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true
                };

                ieOptions.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
                ieOptions.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, ieOptions);
```

You have to set ForceCreateProcessApi at true. It's only with IE that you have to set this kind of options.

And if the program threw an other error like :

"This issue occurs when the following registry entry is set to 0:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth"

You will have to create a key in register (using regedit) and set this key 
to 0  (Type: REG_DWORD and Value Type: Decimal).